# What is this bracket or tool made from steel bar?

Tags: tools

What is this? A tool? Shelf hardware? Something else?

[image: What is this tool?]

Answer (score 8):

It's a single support for a staging plank.

It would require at least one more like it (plus a plank to run between them) to be useful.

The angled slots suggest specifically for holding a toe board (keeps workers from sliding off the edge) at the edge of roofing work, since that allows the support to be shingled over and removed without direct access to the nails holding it in place, but it's not *(what I would call)* a "Roof Jack" with a similar holding arrangement and a board support that can be adjusted to be level or near level on the slope.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/roofing/roofing-jacks)</sub>

Comment: Why is this not a roof jack? That's what I'd call it. Not all have angle adjustment. In fact, I've only ever used 45 and 90 degree fixed types.

Comment: ...because my experience with roof jacks is with adjustable or non-90-degree ones that support a plank you can reasonably walk on or set tools on. I'd personally find the 90° to the roof arrangement annoying to work with, but do see a use for it as the toe board support. Obviously you and whoever is in the picture have a different expectation.

Comment: In most cases it's not practical to walk on the planks. That gives you a very narrow work area. We just walk on the roof up to about 8:12 pitch, and the jacks are for safety backup, catching dropped tools and holding supplies. That, and the term "jack" is comically vague. How many things can we think of that are called a jack?

Comment: thank you @Ecnerwal !

Answer (score -5):

the hook is pretty much a giveaway that is from furniture hardware / shelf hardware.

Comment: No, it isn't. -1.